# How to update opacity of WMS layer in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How do I adjust opacity in leaflet without calling "removeLayer"? I have already used "map.addLayer(myLayer)" to my map. I see that there is a setParams() method, but it appears to have no effect when I call "myLayer.setParams({opacity:0.1})" and there is no refresh button for the WMS. Is this even possible in Leaflet? If so, how? Is there even someway to call something along the lines of "map.getLayers()" or something to be able to retrieve already added layers to the map?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `setOpacity` like `layer.setOpacity(0.5)`

API Docs - http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-opacity (scroll down a bit)

Comment: that link only works once "Options inherited from GridLayer" is expanded under https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer